# Multiple Key Presses in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

Ok, so I am creating a game in XNA, Visual C# 2010 Express Edition.  I have a stick figure which can successfully complete a run cycle, so I then wished to add in a "ducking" feature.  If you hold shift, you can duck- which works.  But then I added an extra layer to my spritesheet with the animation- and declared in the code if shift and A were held down or shift and D, then the animation on the bottom row would cycle through.  It only goes to the next frame and just moves from there, which as I stated in my title, is most likely a result of the program's inability to detect both keypresses at the same time.  Here is an excerpt of my code, any help would appreciated.

```
else if (keyboardstate.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift))
{
    currentFrame.X = 0;
    currentFrame.Y = 8;
}
if (keyboardstate.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift) && keyboardstate.IsKeyDown(Keys.A) && killed == false)
{
    pos.X -= speed;
    this.flip = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;
    leftPress = true;
    timeSinceLastFrame += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
    if (timeSinceLastFrame > millisecondsPerFrame)
    {
        timeSinceLastFrame -= millisecondsPerFrame;
        ++currentFrame.X;
        if (currentFrame.X >= 8)
        {
            currentFrame.X = 0;
        }
    }
}
if (keyboardstate.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift) && keyboardstate.IsKeyDown(Keys.D) && killed == false)
{
    pos.X += speed;
    if (leftPress == true)
    {
        this.flip = SpriteEffects.None;
    }
    timeSinceLastFrame += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
    if (timeSinceLastFrame > millisecondsPerFrame)
    {
        timeSinceLastFrame -= millisecondsPerFrame;
        ++currentFrame.X;
        if (currentFrame.X >= 8)
        {
            currentFrame.X = 0;
        }
    }
}
else if (keyPress.IsKeyUp(Keys.LeftShift) && keyRelease.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift) && killed == false)
{
    currentFrame.X = 0;
    currentFrame.Y = 0;
    leftPress = false;
}
```

P.S. Here is my spritesheet for reference.  :)  http://oi43.tinypic.com/2v1uohg.jpg

P.S.S. Everything here is located in the Update method.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use [GetPressedKeys()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.keyboardstate.getpressedkeys.aspx) that gets an array of values that correspond to the keyboard keys that are currently being pressed. but not sure if this will work due hardware limitation.

```
Keys[] currentPressedKeys = currentKeyboardState.GetPressedKeys();
foreach( Keys key in currentPressedKeys )
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like [key blocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_%28key%29#Key_blocking_and_ghosting). This is not due to the software but due to the keyboard. Many keyboards will fail to recognize various three-key combinations.

For example, my laptop and work keyboards don't recognize several combinations that I have tried to use in my applications. But my gaming keyboard does.